# Expert tutorials/Books for MVC C# Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am familiar enough with C#, objects and classes and i have tested Entity Framework 4 (tutorials, videos, blogs for CRUD operations). But i think this knowledge is not enough for a larger project with real business aspects such us Ajax partial updates, jquery, json data populating lists etc.

Which Books or tutorials do you suggest for Professional Programming with MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the Tutotials in ASP.NET MVC site. They have a nice [Contoso University sample](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) MVC app which uses Entity Framework and Repositary pattern.

You may also consider checking out some Open Source projects in Codeplex/Github and download the source code and try do make some customization. That is a good exercise for sure.

Practicing will make you an expert. So Practice Practice Practice. Write some code...

Answer (score 2):

[ASP.NET MVC in Action](http://manning.com/palermo/), good book to look.

Answer (score 1):

I like the Steve Sanderson MVC book for a good overview of the framework:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-Edition/dp/1430234040/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1344004976&sr=8-4

believe there is an MVC4 version now too, but without Steve:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-NET-Edition-Professional-Apress/dp/1430242361/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1344004976&sr=8-2